# running different script base on extension in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible playbook to run different scripts. I need to change the executable base on the extension. This is my playbook:

```
 - name: run nodejs script
   command: node "{{item}}" arg1
   loop: "{{ lookup('fileglob', '{{path}}/{{deploy_version}}/*.js', wantlist=True) }}"

 - name: running python script
   command: python "{{item}}" arg1
   loop: "{{ lookup('fileglob', '{{path}}/{{deploy_version}}/*.py, wantlist=True) }}"
```

Since there is an order to run the scripts, I need to use an "if, else, statement". But I'm unable to find a way to run scripts in alphabetic order based on extension. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [splitext](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#id8) filter will extract the extension from the filename, which can then be used to lookup the command in a `dict` that maps the file extension to the command, and then it can be applied to all the globs you wish, which if I understand correctly you want to run in alphabetical order regardless of which fileglob it matches.

```
- name: run the scripts
  command: '{{ cmd_by_ext[ item|splitext|last ] }} {{ item }} arg1'
  loop: '{{ (js_files + py_files) | sort }}'
  vars:
    script_dir: '{{ path + "/" + deploy_version }}'
    js_files: '{{ lookup("fileglob", script_dir+"*/.js", wantlist=True) }}'
    py_files: '{{ lookup("fileglob", script_dir+"*/.py", wantlist=True) }}'
    cmd_by_ext:
      '.js': 'node'
      '.py': 'python'
```